# Alt, title and other tags in e-mail html

Tags: html, email, tags, alt

Does it make any sense putting alt, title and other tags on  or  elements in HTML of an e-mail?

Google preety much reads all gmail

and since my clients often send emails with products, is there any sense in putting tags into elements to help google understand what we are mailing to people?

thank you,
em2

Comment: Alt is great, if users client block to donwload the image.

Comment: It makes sense to put tags in e-mail html, otherwise it is not html, by definition. It is a mystery what is being asked here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any sense in putting tags into elements to help Google understand what we are mailing to people?

I wouldn't worry too much about Google, though, yes, it would probably help. But all that does it put more relevant ads on the side, which could potentially be a competitor.

Where they do come in handy though, and why you should use them is for people who have screen readers, and people who block the images. If the images can't be seen, for any reason, **especially for blind(ish) readers**, then there should be an alt attribute describing the image.